# Easy way to determine argument type in argument list

Tags: c, embedded, printf, scanf, avr

I want to have a function debug_print(fmt, args) which takes format string, arguments and build a char buffer which I can then send to UART. Basically I could pass all this to scanf, but the problem is that for formatting float numbers needs special care.

```
dtostrf( float_num, 3, 4, temp_buf );
```

So I need to replace `%f` with `%s` in format string and change float arg to `temp_buf`. All that has to be done in minimum steps, because of limited embedded environment capabilities.

Would appreciate if anyone could help to build such function.

Something like this:

```
void debug_print(char *fmt, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,fmt);
    // use uart function for output
    va_end(args);
}
```

But how to effectively iterate through placeholders and how to substitute `float` arg to `char*`?

Comment: Why would you not simply use vsprintf() to do the work for you?

Comment: If you have limited resources, variable argument lists and stdio.h are both bad ideas. In fact, va_lists is a bad idea in any form of deterministic system: all embedded systems certainly sort under that category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the format string, which will be impossible if the passed string is actually a literal string, when you find the `"%f"` format-code you convert the next argument using your `dtostrf` function, storing the value in a temporary small string, then concatenate that to the output string (i.e. `strcat`).

Comment: So I have to organize loop which is going through each char in fmt, then actually convert placeholder to argument myself? Could you bring some example please?

Comment: @Pablo At least if you can't use e.g. `vsprintf` then you have to implement the formatting yourself. There are plenty of examples available if you search a little.